# Will EV SSL work with Subdirectory storefronts?

Tags: multistore, ce-1.9.1.0, ssl

I want to have:

```
myname.com
myname.com/fr/
myname.com/en/
myname.com/fr/checkout/onepage/
myname.com/en/checkout/onepage/
```

The reason I want to run Magento with sub-directories is so that English speaking customers see the store and checkout cart in their language, and the French speaking customers see the store and checkout in their language.

Will this cause any issues with an EV SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this would not be a problem, a SSL certificate will only check the hostname part to verify its validity. Any path used on that domain is protected with that EV certificate.